# firebase snapshot is not working with node js GCF

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase database structure in this format

[image]

the database is follows this format Ordergroup/groupid/item
I want to get the buyerid for each item once a new group is created in the ordergroup node. So  I try this

```
   exports.sendorderemailtoseller = functions.database.ref('/Ordergroup/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

            const parentRef = snapshot.ref.parent;
            const ref = snapshot.ref;


            const original = snapshot.val();
            const buyerid = original.buyerid;

        })
```

I then notice that original only returns the first child and the buyerid comes out as undefined. How can I get a snapshot of all the child in the groupid excluding Ordersummary?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable 'original' is actually getting the whole tree under node 1522509953304, so you will need to iterate over its children to get each buyerid, like below:

```
exports.sendorderemailtoseller = functions.database.ref('/Ordergroup/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const buyerids = [];
  snapshot.forEach((item) => {
    buyerids.push(item.val().buyerid);
  });
  console.log(buyerids);
});
```